# Positive unbounded self-adjoint operator relatively bounded by sum with another positive unbounded self-adjoint operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive (i.e. $\langle A x, x \rangle \geqslant 0$ and the same for $B$) unbounded self-adjoint operators on a separable complex Hilbert space. Is it true that $A$ is relatively bounded by $A+B$? Or in other words, is it true that there exists constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that for all $x \in \mathcal{D}(A) \cap \mathcal{D}(B)$ (assume the intersection of domains is non-trivial), $$||Ax|| \leqslant C_1||(A+B)x|| + C_2 ||x|| ?$$

I have seen this claimed in a book, but I can't think of how to prove it.

Edit 1: The reference in question is Adiabatic Perturbation Theory in Quantum Dynamics by Stefan Teufel. On page 48, equation (2.36) the second inequality, the author draws a conclusion like the one I am asking about using the fact that the operator $1 \otimes H_{e0}$ (which I called $B$), which is being added to an operator $\epsilon^2 D_A^2 \otimes 1$ (which I called $A$), is bounded below. Here is a screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Edit 2: In the reference there is a tensor product structure at play, however I don't see how this could influence the specific inequality I want to understand, beyond the simple fact that $\epsilon^2 D_A^2 \otimes 1$ and $1 \otimes H_{e0}$ commute. But this isn't mentioned by the author so I suspect its not important.

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer the question in general, but in your specific case, the two operators commuting allows you simultaneously diagonalize $A$ and $B$, so you may assume both are multiplication by positive measurable functions $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ on some suitable measure space. Then $||Ax||^2 = \int A(t)^2|x(t)|^2 d\mu(t)$ and similarly $||(A + B)x||^2 = \int (A(t) + B(t))^2|x(t)|^2 d\mu(t)$, so the result just follows by noting $A(t)^2 \leq (A(t) + B(t))^2$.